# Conditional Formatting from Helloh, for a Noob

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, formatting, colors, conditional-formatting

I'm going to try my best to explain what I need to figure out. Also, for you to understand exactly how mind bending this is for me, I haven't used an Excel formula since 2005/2006ish. We're doing a financial report for work, using Excel 2007, that needs shading for four different conditions. As an example (IF G5 is 0-80% of H5, shade G5 color 1), obviously that's not a real formula, but as previously stated I'm no longer familiar with formula's and it sounded good to me lol. From there it'd be something like IF G5 is 80-90% of H5 = color 2, IF 90-120% color 3, then IF 120+% color 4. I apologize if I made it sound more complicated than it really is, but I have a quite a few paired cells to do this formula for, so I'm kind of freaking out.

Answer (score 2):

Once you select the cells that you want to format, you can find the Conditional Formatting drop-down on the ribbon, which gives you loads of pre-set rules to choose from, like color scales.

[image]

This will automatically color the items based on the range they are in…

[image]

You can also create your own rule to color only cells that fit within a certain range, or greater than a certain number.

[image]

This rule will only color cells greater than a certain amount, with the color you specify.

[image]

This can be very useful, and you should note that you can apply a second rule to the same range. For instance, here is a second rule that colored items larger than 2000 with green instead of red.

[image]

You can even create a completely customized rule by choosing the New Formatting Rule option.

[image]

If you’ve applied too many rules and want to start over, just select the cells and use the Clear Rules option to remove all the formatting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the share! It helped me understand conditional formatting a little more, but unfortunately I still don't understand if there's a formula I can use to make things a little less complicated. I'd post the file/a screenshot to make it easier to understand, but my rep is too low. What I get from this post is that I have to manually calculate the percentages, then run a "between" type deal. I can get it done like this, but I counted at least 152 individual "between" formula's that have to be entered, and if the number that's getting the percentage changes, I'm back at square one.